# How can I run View after the viewmodel run in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, view, triggers

My code is like that.
`MyView` is a user control

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
    <vw:MyView d:DesignWidth="150" d:DesignHeight="100" />
</DataTemplate>
```

This is my tabcontrol -> tabitem datatemplate. I'm creating a new tab, tab is being created but MyView is not loading in the tab until I focused the tab.

When the application create the MyViewModel in a scenario, MyView doesnt populated until I focus the the MyView. How can I populate MyView immediately after the MyViewModel populated?

**UPDATE**

Firstly this is a custom TabControl inherits the Wpf TabControl...

```
      <dragablz:TabablzControl 
            Margin="0 -1 -1 0" 
            SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged"
            HeaderPrefixContent="{StaticResource WindowIcon}"
            AdjacentHeaderItemOffset="0"
            x:Name="TabControl">

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:BrowserTabViewModel}">
            <view:BrowserTabView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <dragablz:TabablzControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:BrowserTabViewModel}">
                <view:BrowserTabView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </dragablz:TabablzControl.ContentTemplate>
    </dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

---

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}}">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource TrapezoidDragableTabItemStyle}" />
            <Setter Property="NewItemFactory" Value="{x:Static common2:MainWindow.NewItemFactory}" />
            <Setter Property="ShowDefaultAddButton" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ShowDefaultCloseButton" Value="True" />

            <Setter Property="CustomHeaderItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemContainerTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:BrowserTabViewModel}">
                        <DockPanel Width="120px" Height="22">
                            <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding Favicon}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Margin="0 0 3 0"
                                   gif:ImageBehavior.AutoStart="True"
                                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                                   RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Opacity="100"
                                   Width="16" Height="16"></Image>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                       Background="Transparent" Margin="0 0 5 0" 
                                       FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       Width="100px" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        </DockPanel>

                    </ItemContainerTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: very interesting.. In follow.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in MyView initialize, tell us when it gets called.

Comment: MyView constructor doesnt run until I focused the tab.

Comment: show me the way that you bind the ViewModel with the DataContext of your view